# How to change the font of the textfield in a table view

Tags: iphone

Objective C is new for me. How can I change the font of a text field in a table view? Here's the code I have now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

if (indexPath.section==0) 
    {
        UITextField *textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 205, 21)];
        textField.placeholder = @" ";
            //textField.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        textField.tag = indexPath.row;
            //textField.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
            //textField.placeholder = [TeamBDict objectAtIndex:textField.tag];
        textField.delegate = self;
        cell.accessoryView = textField;
        [textField release];
    }
```

Comment: the commented line will do the same. `textField.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];`

Comment: Please read stackoverflow's FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
```

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW1) you should have read.

Comment: There isn't a `textLabel` property for a `UITextField` (Xcode probably told you that), only a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the text field's font is as simple as setting it's `font` property:

```
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:16.0];
```

The code you've provided needs some work, though. -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is expected to return a table cell. You'll want to read the [*Table View Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 iOS 10.x answer

```
textField.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textfield.font = UIFont(name:"whatever u choose language type here",size:17)
```